# Could not load locally hosted web server in cypress

Tags: vagrant, cypress

I am trying to set up a cypress test suite for my project, but I keep encountering the error message when running the test suite:

```
Sorry, we could not load:

http://dev.project.local/signup/test
```

My cypress config looks like this:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://dev.project.local",
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "hosts": {
    "dev.project.local": "192.168.10.10"
},
```

I have a web server that is host locally on a vagrant VM. I have also added an entry to my local hosts file:

```
192.168.10.10   dev.project.local
```

These are the error messages I am getting from cypress:

```
cy.visit() failed trying to load:


http://dev.project.local/signup/test

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.

We received this error at the network level:

  > Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/

Common situations why this would fail:
  - you don't have internet access
  - you forgot to run / boot your web server
  - your web server isn't accessible
  - you have weird network configuration settings on your computer
cypress/integration/examples/window.spec.js:10:8
   8 |   it('cy.window() - get the global window object', () => {
   9 |     // https://on.cypress.io/window
> 10 |     cy.visit('/signup/test')
     |        ^
  11 |     cy.window().should('have.property', 'top')
  12 |   })
  13 |
```

> - you don't have internet access

I do

> - you forgot to run / boot your web server

It is running

> - your web server isn't accessible

I can access the web server fine though `dev.project.local`

> - you have weird network configuration settings on your computer

maybe, I don't think I do but its possible that cypress doesn't work well with subdomains or vagrant

This is the error code from the console:

```
at <unknown> (http://dev.project.local/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:157829:24)
    at visitFailedByErr (http://dev.project.local/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:157189:13)
    at <unknown> (http://dev.project.local/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:157828:12)
From previous event:
    at go (http://dev.project.local/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:157791:18)
    at <unknown> (http://dev.project.local/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:157857:21)
From previous event:
    at visit (http://dev.project.local/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:157855:39)
    at Context.visit (http://dev.project.local/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:157864:15)
From Your Spec Code:
    at Context.eval (webpack:///cypress/integration/examples/window.spec.js:10:8)
From Node.js Internals:
    Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/
      at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:469:23)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:315:21)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:13)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:10)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:11)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:24)
```

Is there something I am missing from my cypress.json? I am at a loss here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't access that URL because it is not on the Internet. Have you tried creating a proxy? (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration.html#Set-a-proxy-on-Linux-or-macOS)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, I had to pass the [host parameter](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options#server-host) to `vite` when starting up my local server:

```
vite --host
```

Comment: It's not a vite project, it's webpack.